# Amazon app Game Controller requirement notification

Tags: android, amazon-fire-tv, gamecontroller

I have an app in the Amazon store that is targeted for Fire TV (box and stick). It works great just using the remote. However when starting the app, there is an annoying notification to the user 'Game Controller Not Detected - It appears that *appName* requires a Game Controller that is not connected to your Fire TV'. Below this is a button 'Launch' and indeed the app launches and performs fine with the remote, but I must get rid of that message.

Combing through the Amazon documentation has been unhelpful. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Comment: my guess is when you submit it you should ask them to *not* mark GameController as required

Comment: Well, thank you, that certainly sounded promising but I didn't see anywhere that I could mark it myself or to request that they mark it

Comment: just add it to the testing notes. when I had issues with a submission that seemed the best way to communicate

Comment: I believe you're right  - but saying this is the best way to communicate is an understatement - it seems to be the ONLY way to communicate with Amazon. Since my app was already submitted, I had no choice but to write to their support - twice  - and NOT get an answer - twice! Taking into consideration the lack of info regarding Amazon app building, they are not exactly being inviting for developers.

Comment: I now added  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.gamepad" android:required="false"/> to the manifest as per Android documentation, and it STILL shows the notification!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an Amazon bug after all. They simply removed the 'Game Controller Not Detected' notification from my app (months after writing to them 3 times, they finally responded)

Answer (score 0):

It is from requiring `android.hardware.touchscreen` in your manifest (done by default so if you have nothing there then it's required as per the default state.)

Override and break the default requirement using:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false"/>
```